# How to get Apache HTTP response code (or first line of server response) with PHP

Tags: php, apache2, httpresponse

How can I get the first line of the servers' HTTP response (Apache2 in my case) for use in my PHP scripts? For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Etc.
```

Or better yet, get just the HTTP response code that my server sends to the client.

To my surprise, [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) doesn't have it. [http_response_code()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) seems to only get the response code if it's first been set by PHP. [apache_response_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php) doesn't seem to have it. [get_headers()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) seems like it would require an extra step/connection (correct me if I'm wrong).

If I set `ErrorDocument 403 /index.php` in httpd.conf, I can use `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]` to get the response code from PHP, but is there another way?

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I find it odd that `$_SERVER` returns almost every bit of data except for the first line of the response or the response code. Maybe it's a general limitation between the HTTP protocol/server technology/PHP? Maybe I shouldn't be trying to access this info in my PHP scripts?

Comment: Surely if your script is running, it's 200 unless you've set it to something else yourself or you're in an errordocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: NO IT'S NOT POSSIBLE** Unless you proxy your own requests. Send your request to a Public facing URL and then redirect them to an internal variant and you get to see the headers in the process. But it's not an easy feat and performance taxing also. Or you can write a Http Server extension and see where that takes you :)

Example:

- request comes to /page.html
- you append ?proxy=true and forward to /page.html?proxy=true
- attempt to load new URL internally forwarding the original request to you internal handler
- check in your internal handling for all $_GET['proxy'] === 'true' requests come from local IP
- if you have a proxy === true then handle this the usual way
- /page.html gets data from /page.html?proxy=true
- logs headers
- forwards data back to original client
- *(not very easy and performance taxing if done wrong)*

**FIRST ATTEMPTS AT ANSWERING**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php - may be this one?

But this works for the headers you are about to send...

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    // Headers are really sent here, do some comparison
    var_dump(headers_list());
});
```

**.htaccess** variant that directs all missing files to index.php.

```
RewriteEngine on
#If handler file is missing, pull index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,NC]
```

Try this.

Comment: I looked at that function, but you're right. It doesn't get the servers' response headers.

Comment: @Jeff You can't get the server's response headers unless you do a request yourself. Just try this function after you send some output. And compare stuff... When you send output headers don't change anymore. Make sure if you do requests to your own URL, you don't end up in a loop :)

Comment: I don't understand why I can get all of the other $_SERVER variables, but not the first line of the response. Maybe the first line/response code is special.

Comment: @Jeff First line is "HTTP/Ver.Ver CODE Error Message". By default it's 200 but can change by you or internal server errors. You can trace it from the server logs after it was sent.

Comment: The only thing being returned is 1 item in an array: `string(23) "Content-type: text/html"`, so I assume that `headers_list()` only takes into account headers being set by PHP. Either that or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Jeff Yes. That's true. But what's the problem... are you unsure of the headers sent? Don't know how to send a status code yourself? I'll paste you code if you need it.

Comment: @Jeff You should explain what you need to accomplish and I might give you an alternate method.

Comment: Appreciate that. I want to pipe everything (standard requests, server errors, etc.) through index.php. If the response code is 4xx-5xx, I want index.php to handle it. The only way I've found to do this is by setting `ErrorDocument 4xx /index.php` in Apache and use `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]`. I thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: @Jeff RewriteRules :) See how easy that was.

Comment: Haha, I've got that already, but it still doesn't send my PHP script the correct server response code (think 400 Bad Request). If you want to change your answer to "No. It's not possible.", I'll mark your answer right.

Comment: @Jeff changed the answer and gave you a final hint but it's overkill and you must be very careful how you forward data to your handling URL and then send it back to client. Like each URL could add &proxy=true and load itself.

Comment: I certainly appreciate the effort. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff ... thanks, see my final edit. It's your best bet if you really want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the response code of a remote host or the local machine? In the first case you could "ping" the machine using a CURL request with the header option set and retrieve various settings of the response header.

Comment: I'm asking for the response code of the local server. Thus, cURL isn't what I'm after.